# page shows short code not output

Tags: functions, shortcode

Written the following code in a custom file inside the theme folder and called it via `functions.php` but at page `[product_first_img]` shows shortcode text, not output.

```
function gal_first_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'size' => ''
    ), $atts));

    $image_size = 'medium';
    if ($size = !'') {
        $image_size = $size;
    }

    $images = get_children(
        array(
            'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        )
    );

    if ($images) {
        $gallery = '';
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $gallery .= wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, $image_size);
        }
        $gallery .= '';
        return $gallery;
    }
}

add_shortcode('product_first_img', 'gal_first_shortcode');
```

Comment: The shortcode is working fine in my local environment. Except for the attachment things I didn't test. Apart from that, you should initiate `$gallery = '';` before the line `if ($images) {` and should `return $gallery` outside the `if` conditional. If the code still doesn't work, you can go with output buffering with `ob_start();` at the beginning of the output and `return ob_get_clean();` when the function ends.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I have put above code in plugin and its working previously is was coded inside functions.php file

Answer (score 0):

I change the array in get_children() and foreach loop with below reference url and code work fine. please check the argument that you have passed also use echo statement like they shown in the example.

reference url : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_children/

let me know result or errors

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent'    => $post_id,
    'post_status'    => null,
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
);

$attachments = get_children( $args );

if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' ) : wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
        echo '<img src="' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID ) ) . '" class="current" />';
    }
}
```